# react vite modules are not working i have imported 10 times but not working

Tags: reactjs, module, vite

react vite modules are not working i have imported 10 times but not working ... today i started react router but these imports are very hard or that is due to vite

[screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2PQn.png)
i tried same to same with myself and with the help me chatgpt but its not solving the error

Comment: Does the file exist? Show your file tree

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you trying to **import the CSS** file from the component folder, which I believe in the style folder have looked into your file structure and properly imported it.

```
.jsx =../component/.jsx
```

```
.css =../style/.css
```